# Mapping LUNs to drive slots on a MSA2312i?

Tags: storage, hp, storage-area-network, hp-modular-smart-array

I'm working with an older MSA2312i. I really need map the current LUN configuration to associated slots via the SSH so I can make it scriptable. Is there a ready way to do so?

I would have thought a `show config` `show vdisks` or `show volumes` would have done it, but nothing provides this particular piece of information.

The CLI manual also proved useless.

EDIT:

What I'm really after would be something that displays like this (mockup from `show config` with the additional item I want included as the last entry).

```
Slot  Serial Vendor   Version  Usage   Interface  Size     Rate  Health  Active Array
1.1   XXXXX  ATA      SN06     VDISK   SATA       1000.2GB 3.0   OK      **7**
```

Really *any* CLI method that would associate the slot number to the array a disk is currently being used for would work however.

Comment: Can you significantly expand on this Tim

Comment: @Chopper3 I've expanded on this with an example. Not sure how much further I can go.